# Create email accounts for my website users using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I have account on smarterasp shared host. I have a website  **mysite.com** with many users and I want to give each user an email attached to my domain like  this username@mysite.com 
the question is:

**How can I create emails on mail.mysite.com smtp server using c#?**

Comment: make email accounts with a language?? your question is very unclear

Comment: Unlikely unless SmarterAsp has a developer API that allows this. I did take a look at their API and couldn't see anything to this effect. Have you contacted SmarterAsp support for help?

Comment: no,  I did not expect that it needs any API.
I asked them for help and I am waiting for their response. thanks

Comment: I contacted ٍSmarterAsp support.. and their response was  "You can create email accounts via control panel only so, it is not something you can do programmatically"

Comment: Just contact their customer support for more information. Every hosting providers have their own policy.